# how to create a simple progress bar loop in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Since I can't find an exact thread like this elsewhere I will post this question here,
I just started learning Tkinter and facing problems with the progress bar widget.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import time
root=Tk()
p = ttk.Progressbar(root,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=200,mode="determinate",takefocus=True,maximum=100)
p['value']=0
p.pack()
for x in range(5):
    p['value']+=20
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.after(1000)
root.mainloop()
```

I can't find the exact problem I first tried time.sleep it doesn't work then I was told to use 'after' it still doesn't work I can make a looping progress bar ar with a function and button but i really wanna start the loading bar just as the Tkinter starts.

hope someone points out the problem, Thank you!!

Comment: `root.after(1000)` is nearly identical to `time.sleep(1)`. So technically you aren't using `.after` for what it was created for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. I have used a function to start the progress bar.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
p = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode="determinate",
                    takefocus=True, maximum=100)
p['value'] = 0
p.pack()

def start():
    if p['value'] < 100:
        p['value'] += 20

        root.after(1000, start)

root.after(1000, start)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you added a button that's not what i want if it is possible to start it as soon as window starts

Comment: @Legend_recalls check out the updated answer

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `root.update_idletasks()`.

Comment: ok sorry for late reply i was studying threads but this is perfectly simple ty

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try thread.. not sure if this is what u want. as follows

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import time, _thread

def progressbar(parent):
    pb = Progressbar(parent, length=100, mode='indeterminate', maximum=100, value=50)
    pb.pack(padx=2, pady=2, expand=YES, fill=X)
    return pb
    
def run(pb):
    pb.update()

def test(val, pb):
    for i in range(val):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.01)
    pb.stop()   

def double(pb):
    _thread.start_new_thread(run, (pb,))
    _thread.start_new_thread(test, (200, pb))

root = Tk()
global pb
a = progressbar(root)
a.start()
double(a)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: well you can add that in comments since i think it's not a good habit to ask again in answers but good luck :)

Comment: This is not an answer. Please delete it.

Comment: two threads have been used to run separately and the progressbar will be stopped by the function when the function ends.. You can use destroy() if you want to remove the progressbar.

Comment: @pukiwawa This answer uses a lot of techniques that are considered bad practice. First of all why are you using `_thread` instead of `threading`. Modules that start with an underscore aren't supposed to be used by the user like: `_thread`, `_io`, `_tkinter`. Also using threads when using `tkinter` can be very dangerous. If you use threads when using `tkinter`, it is possible to crash python without an error traceback. That will make the problem undebuggable.

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks for your advice. I am still consider new to python. just started to learn since Feb 2021. I could not think of other better way to have progress bar and function running both at he same time, just like when "loading".. so far i can only think of threading..

Answer (score 0):

Threading is another good way to use with progress bar in tkinter, just make sure you update the window every times.

```
from tkinter import ttk, Tk
from tkinter import *
import time, threading
root=Tk()
p = ttk.Progressbar(root,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=200,mode="determinate",takefocus=True,maximum=100)
p['value']=0
p.pack()
def update():
    for x in range(5):
        p['value']+=20
        root.update()
        time.sleep(1)
threading.Thread(target=update).start()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: isnt update already a function ur defining update again but this works i will look into threads more after this thankyou

Comment: `tkinter` does not support multithreading — only one thread can access it in a program that has more than one thread. In other words threading is not a good way to do this.

Comment: `tkinter` is support multithreading but it need to update the window. `tkinter` error because it window have not been updated.

Comment: @MHP No @ martineau is right, `tkinter` doesn't support threading look at [this](https://pastebin.com/N1d8Z62R). It crashes python without an error traceback.

Comment: this is nearlyp erfect but i liked the accepted answer for its simplicity

Comment: @TheLizzard you see in the code what? it set `daemon=True` but using `root.destroy()`?

Comment: @MHP Usually all threads are supposed to have `daemon=True`. Even if you remove it, the problem is still there.

Comment: @TheLizzard no youre wrong, when you remove it, the root not have any thing inside it, you must put `root.mainloop()` so the root can work.

Comment: @MHP You don't really need a `root.mainloop()` when making small examples of `tkinter` code. But I will create an example with `root.mainloop()` for you

Comment: @TheLizzard i've tried already, but why you don't try to remove Thread and just put the root inside with out `root.mainloop()` ?

Comment: @MHP Look at [this](https://pastebin.com/sNijL6gm). It's improved an no longer uses `del root` and has a `root.mainloop()`. Now imagine something similar in your code. Maybe a button calls `root.destroy()` instead of the `root.after(..., root.destroy)`. How would you try to debug it. It's nearly impossible to debug. Also the code proves that `tkinter` is not thread safe.

Comment: @MHP Try adding `Button(root, text="Click me", command=root.destroy).pack()` to your answer and click the button while the progressbar is loading. it will raise a `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop`. Hopefully that proves to you that `tkinter` is not thread safe and should only be used from one thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235875/discussion-between-mhp-and-thelizzard).